# mongodb/mongoose - how to insert new subdocument with a nested array field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Original question**: how to insert `type` as a field name.

So I'm getting the error:

```
CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{ details:\n   [ { content: \'\',\n       hidden: false,\n       _id: \'5b83ed6410bd2b146b13741b\',\n       title: \'Name\',\n       order: 0 },\n     { content: \'\',\n       hidden: false,\n       _id: \'5b83ed6410bd2b146b13741a\',\n       title: \'Price\',\n       order: 1 },\n     { content: \'\',\n       hidden: false,\n       _id: \'5b83ed6410bd2b146b137419\',\n       title: \'Company\',\n       order: 2 } ] }" at path "items"
```

here's the object:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Name",
        "content": "",
        "hidden": false,
        "order": 0,
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "title": "Price",
        "content": "",
        "hidden": false,
        "order": 1,
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "title": "Company",
        "content": "",
        "hidden": false,
        "order": 2,
        "type": "text"
    }
]
```

I have the query:

```
ListModel
    .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: list_id
        },
        {   
            $push: {
                items: {
                    details: the_template
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

which is trying to make an insertion/update

I'm not sure what the error is.

**Noting** that I am inserting a new `item` into the `items` array. It works if I create the item first, then update that item with a `$push: {details}` query.

Here are the schemas.

List Schema:

```
var List = new Schema(
    {
        items: {
            index: true,
            type: [Item]
        },
        hidden: {
            default: false,
            index: true,
            type: Boolean
        },
        name: {
            index: true,
            type: String,
        },
        item_details_template: {
            default: [
                {
                    "title": "Name",
                    "content": "",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "order": 0,
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Price",
                    "content": "",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "order": 1,
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Company",
                    "content": "",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "order": 2,
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ],
            type: [Item_Detail]
        },
        // Other users who have access
        shared_with: {
            index: true,
            refs: "users",
            type: [Shared_With]
        },
        // Owner
        user_id: {
            index: true,
            ref: "users",
            required: true,
            type: ObjectId,
        }
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
)
```

Item Schema:

```
var Item = new Schema(
    {
        // Template_Item
        based_on: {
            index: true,
            type: ObjectId
        },
        details: {
            default: [],
            index: true,
            type: [Item_Detail],
        },
        display_name: {
            default: "",
            index: true,
            type: String,
        },
        image: {
            default: "http://via.placeholder.com/700x500/ffffff/000000/?text=No%20Image&",
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
        hidden: {
            default: true,
            index: true,
            type: Boolean
        },
        tags: {
            default: [],
            index: true,
            type: [Tag]
        }
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
)
```

ItemDetail Schema:

```
var Item_Detail = new Schema(
    {
        content: {
            default: "",
            index: true,
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            validate: {
                validator(v)
                {
                    if (this.title.trim() === "price")
                    {
                        return !isNaN(v.trim())
                    }
                    return true
                }
            }
        },
        hidden: {
            default: false,
            index: true,
            type: Boolean
        },
        order: {
            index: true,
            required: true,
            type: Number
        },
        table: {
            default: {},
            type: Mixed
        },
        title: {
            required: true,
            index: true,
            type: String,
        },
        type: {
            default: "text",
            enum: ["text", "table"],
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
)
```

Comment: please post your schema code

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet edited with the schemas. Now that I think about it, it might be because I'm not pushing ItemDetail schema, though I'm sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose field with the name type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100013/mongoose-field-with-the-name-type)

Comment: You are pushing in nested array and that's why you are getting this error... You have to use `$` positional operator or `arrayFilters` to update nested arrays... Few links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893392/update-an-array-in-an-embedded-document/51893590#51893590
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706647/update-deeply-nested-array-in-mongodb/51708522#51708522
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916388/remove-element-from-nested-array-mongodb/51917381#51917381https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697951/update-nested-array-with-multiple-conditions-in-mongodb/51697989#51697989

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697951/update-nested-array-with-multiple-conditions-in-mongodb/51697989#51697989
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605347/update-nested-array-objects-based-on-a-property-in-mongodb/51605458#51605458

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet what I'm trying to do is insert a new `item` into `items`, but with a new `details`.  If I just run `$push: { items: {} }` it works fine and correctly inserts a new `item`.

Comment: yes I know it will work for single nested array `$push: { items: {} }` but for the multiple you have use operators just as I mentioned in the above links

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet When I tried it, it said it couldn't find the position. I'm actually doing a creation of a new `item` element, so it basically doesn't exist at the time. if I also do `$detail` or `$.detail`, it says the field can't start with the dollar sign.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet found the issue, was due to the declaration of variables.

Comment: Great!!! Cheers man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was giving this error was due to the definition of variables. `Item` was being declared before `Item_Detail`, which means it had no access to `Item_Detail` at the time.

I.e.

```
var Item = new Schema(...) // Item_Detail is referenced in here
var Item_Detail = new Schema(...)
```

fixed with

```
var Item_Detail = new Schema(...) // declare before
var Item = new Schema(...)
```